# How to modify SpaCy infix pattern to avoid token splitting on apostrophe between letters

Tags: python, regex, spacy

I am looking at one of Spacy's infixes:
`r"(?<=[{al}{q}])\.(?=[{au}{q}])".format(al=ALPHA_LOWER, au=ALPHA_UPPER, q=CONCAT_QUOTES)` but am having trouble figuring out exactly what it means. Is it lowercase followed but quote character followed by period follow by uppercase followed by quote character? Like `b'.X'`?

Essentially I am trying to edit this so that it does not split on `'` between alpha characters. So `dk'd` stays `dk'd` instead of splitting into `['dk','d']`

When I ran it (phrase matcher script), one of the patterns to match was "DK". It matched "DK" on "dk'd" , I'm assuming because it split it into "dk" and "d", which I don't want.

Comment: Sorry, I have just tried to tokenize `Apple is looking at dk'd`, and it comes out as expected, `[Apple, is, looking, at, dk'd]`. The regex is quite simple: if matches `.` that is preceded with a lowercase letter or quote and is followed with an uppercase letter or quote. I do not think it will help you with the `dk'd` tokenization.

Comment: Which spacy version are you using? Mine splits it.

Comment: It is SpaCy v.2.3.0, `nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")`, `doc = nlp("Apple is looking at dk'd")`, `print([x for x in doc])` => `[Apple, is, looking, at, dk'd]`

Comment: I am using 2.2.4. Strange, I get your result now after re-running it. So technically it shouldn't split there, correct? My output it matched "dk" on "dk'd".

Comment: What do you mean by "*My output it matched "dk" on "dk'd"*"?

Comment: Initially when I ran it (phrase matcher script), one of the patterns to match was "DK". It matched "DK" on "dk'd" , I'm assuming because it split it into "dk" and "d"

Comment: What is your `pattern` for phrase matcher?

Comment: The pattern is "DK".

Comment: Is it `TEXT`? `REGEX`? Show the code.

Comment: I found the issue. `doc = nlp(" ".join(re.split('\W+', whole_text)))`. I was splitting before I was calling nlp.

Comment: Right, `\W` matches `'`. You may try `doc = nlp(" ".join(re.split('[^\w']+', whole_text)))`